# Not matching regular expression for Unicode characters in Excel VBA

Tags: regex, vba, excel, unicode

How do I use the regular expression for not matching scenario for uni-code characters in Excel VBA.

**Requirement**

```
xxx業務データxxx         - Match (if contains 業務データ character)
xxx定義。業務データxxx - Not match (if contains 定義。eventhough 業務データ character exists)
```

I have tried with the following regular expression but not getting the proper result. Please guide me or correct me where I was wrong.

```
 - Regex pattern: ^(?!定義。)業務データ
   - 定義。業務データxxx    - Not match (As expected)
   - 業務データxxx          - Match (As expected)
   - xxx業務データxxx       - Not match (Failed)
   - xxx定義。業務データxxx - Not match (As expected)

 - Regex pattern: (?!定義。)業務データ
   - 定義。業務データxxx    - Match (Failed)
   - 業務データxxx         - Match (As expected)
   - xxx業務データxxx      - Match (As expected)
   - xxx定義。業務データxxx - Match (Failed)
```

Tried here http://regexr.com/3gd4g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following regex:

```
^(?!.*定義。).*業務データ.*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/P8Jmvg/1)

The pattern works like this:

- `^` - start of a string
- `(?!.*定義。)` - a negative lookahead that tries to match any 0+ chars other than line break chars (`.*`) as many as possible and then `定義。` char sequence, and if found, the whole string is failed
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars (`.*`) as many as possible
- `業務データ`  - a literal substring
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars (`.*`) as many as possible
- `$`  - end of string

Comment: Worked. Thank you. Also thank you very much for the explanation as well.

Comment: @GrabNewTech: I decided to post my answer because the one posted by selvarjmas contains no explanation and is about 30% slower due to the overlapping quantified subpatterns (`(.*text.*)*` inside   a pattern makes the regex engine perform redundant backtracking and may even cause a crash/freeze).

Answer (score 1):

Try the following regex

```
^((?!.*定義。.*))(.*業務データ.*)*$
```

**Result**

```
- Regex pattern: ^((?!.*定義。.*))(.*業務データ.*)*$
   - 定義。業務データxxx     - Not match (As expected)
   - 業務データxxx          - Match (As expected)
   - xxx業務データxxx       - Match (As expected)
   - xxx定義。業務データxxx -  Not match (As expected)
   - xxx定義業務データxxx   -  Match (As expected)
```

Here is the link : http://regexr.com/3gd4s